# Facebook Graph API: Get likes given by a Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

On my Facebook Page I 'like' specific posts from other users. This way I can easily include these likes on my website using the following FQL queries:

```
"query1 = "SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, created_time, permalink FROM stream WHERE 'PAGE_ID' IN likes.sample AND filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = PAGE_ID LIMIT 0,".$limit,

"query2" => "SELECT id, name, url, pic_square FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)"
```

Unfortunately, this will not be possible anymore with the new Graph API 2(.2).

Does someone know how to do this with the new Facebook Graph API?

For now I can use the following workaround:
1. Get the Page's likes and posts with `/{page-id}/feed`
2. Extract posts from other users that are liked by the page. This is possible since all the posts contain the property 'likes'.

The drawback with this workaround is that /feed can only return the latest 250 items. It is (in theory) possible that I didn't like any of the 250 latests posts.

Thank you!